# Cannot measure Icons properly

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

This

```
    Layout( content = {
        Icon(
            painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Filled.CloudDownload),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.upload),
            tint = Color(0xFFD0FFF7)
        )
    } ){measurables, constraints ->

        val upload = measurables[0].measure(constraints.copy(minHeight = constraints.maxHeight / 10))

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight / 10){
            upload.place(0, 0) // or relative, doesn't matter
        }
    }
```

still yields some sort of default dimensions. Even if I max it out to the entire screen.

Please note, in contradiction, `Modifier.height(...)` and the width equivalent works just fine.

Even the fillMaxHeight and width Modifiers do not size the visual. There seems to be a transparent (or white maybe) area around that actually gets resized.

Comment: Could you add code which doesn't work? How do you try to "max it out to the entire screen"?

Comment: Sir that is the code. This does not render the desired size

Comment: It should be the tenth of the screen hieght, but it is quite small

Comment: Probably some sort of default height

Comment: Oh the "max it out" part. I'm sorry. I don't do t dynamically. I was just trying to say that I have tried doing that as well. Just replacing the `constraints.maxHeight / 10` to just `constraints.maxHeight`. It will max it out. It seems as if the widged is indedd maximised but the Icon that a user can see is not

Comment: The visible stuff is not sized correctly